# THREE.JS : display image on objects issue

Tags: javascript, file-upload, three.js, textures

I am currently creating a webpage in three.js and I struggle to display an image on an object. What I want to do is to display an image on a Mesh with PlaneGeometry.

I first tried to load my image as a texture to replace the material of my mesh but it failed it doesn't display anything (even the object disappeared).

To create and display my object I used these lines of code (scene is my scene and onglets is the group in which I gathered several objects (onglet1, onglet2, ...)):

```js
    couleur = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x031f3c , side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    plan = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.75 , 0.4 );
    var onglets = new THREE.Group();

    onglet1 = new THREE.Mesh( plan , couleur );
    onglet1.position.set( 0, 0, r );
    onglets.add(onglet1);
    scene.add(onglets);
```

To load my image I modified my code like this:

```js
    couleur = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x031f3c , side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    plan = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.75 , 0.4 );
    var onglets = new THREE.Group();

    var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "../media/groupe.jpg" );
    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: 0x000000 } );

    onglet1 = new THREE.Mesh( plan , material );
    onglet1.position.set( 0, 0, r );
    onglets.add(onglet1);
    scene.add(onglets);
```

If you see what I did wrong or have any advice to improve my code in general I would be happy to hear it.
Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Comment: `SpriteMaterial` is for `Sprite` object. For `Mesh`, there are `MeshXXXMaterial`. Try to use, for example `var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: map } );` and no need to use `color: 0x000000` as it means you multiply color values of texture channel-wise with 0, thus, you'll get a pure black material.

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849 ! I modidied var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: 0x000000 } ); and changed it for var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: map } );

Now it displays the object but completely black...

Comment: Check, if your texture is loaded properly (correct path). Any warnings in the console?

Comment: I just rechecked the path, it's correct, and thee console doesn't display anything, that's why I don't understand, what could go wrong. I have the same problem when I want to create a skybox for my scene, everything goes well until I render the scene and nothing appears (I mean everything appear except the skybox), just a black background